# how to write the following in LINQ syntax

Tags: sql, linq

Just wondering how to write the following SQL in LINQ syntax

```
select U.Id, U.FirstName, U.Surname, 
(select COUNT(COESNo) from COESDetails where InspectorId = U.Id) as Count
from UserDetails U
where U.AppearOnReport = 1
```

either Fluent or Query Expression, or Both

Thanks

Comment: By using below/software you can easily convert your SQL query into LinqQuery.
 
http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fluent syntax is

```
db.UserDetails.Where(ud => ud.AppearOnReport).Select(ud =>
    new {
        ud.Id,
        ud.FirstName,
        ud.Surname,
        Count = db.COESDetails.Count(c => c.InspectorId == ud.Id)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from u in db.UserDetails
join c in db.COESDetails on u.Id equals c.InspectorId into uc
where u.AppearOnReport == 1
select new {
   u.Id,
   u.FirstName,
   u.Surname,
   Count = uc.Count()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing here directly, without having a C# compiler opened but it should work:

```
using(var context = new DataContext())
{
     var query = from detail in context.UserDetails
                 where detail.AppearOnReport = 1
                 select new
                 {
                        Id = detail.Id,
                        FirstName = detail.FirstName,
                        Surname = detail.Surname,
                        Count = context.COESDetails.Count(li => li.InspectorId = detail.Id)
                 };
}
```

The problem of this query is that takes all the columns from the UserDetails table (or i think so that). I remember that you could specify somehow to take only certain columns, and not all the mapped columns from the entity.

Anyway, you can check my query using the SQL Profiler. If you want to play more with link there is a tool for that:  [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks much appreciated.. is there a way from LINQPad to convert a sql query to LINQ?